# Concat single column fields using GROUP BY

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there any way to combine/concat the fields within one column by grouping them.
Eg:

```
col1   col2
1     aa
1     bb
1     cc
2     dd
2     ee
```

I want to query something like :

```
select col1, concat(col2) from tableName group by col1;
```

Output should be :

```
1    aa,bb,cc
2    dd,ee
```

Is there any function in hive to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you have a table `test` as follows:

```
select id, val from test order by id, val;     
2   aa
2   bb
1   bb
1   aa
```

You can use the `HIVE` function `collect_set`:

```
select id, collect_set(val) from test group by id;
1   ["aa","bb"]
2   ["bb","aa"]
```

But note that `collect_set` returns a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated.

You can find more details at the [Language Manual Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

Answer (score 12):

you can use concat_ws() and collect_list() to achieve this....

Something like

```
select id , concat_ws(",", collect_list(val)) from test group by id;
```

"," is the seperator in the above query.

Comment: Never use "," as the separator, you will have so many problems in the later stages.. Use ":" or something that does not conflict with a csv.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group_concat() to achive this:

```sql
select col1,group_concat(col2) from test group by col1;
```

the default seperator is ',', you can appoint sepreator just like:

```sql
select col1,group_concat(col2 separator ';') from test group by col1;
```

Comment: Hive does not have any function with name `group_concat` among the built-in UDAFs

Comment: maybe you can see this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028484/hive-group-concat-with-order-by