# Concatenate values from the same column grouping by and in a certain order

Tags: sql, hive

Using Hive, I need to concatenate the values from the column **message** for each different **id**. 
Starting from a table like this:

| id | message | nro |
| --- | --- | --- |
| juan | como estas | 2 |
| juan | hola | 1 |
| pedro | hello | 1 |
| pedro | how u doin | 2 |

And getting a table like this:

| id | messages |
| --- | --- |
| juan | hola;como estas |
| pedro | hello;how u doin |

The concatenation must follow an ascending order coming from **nro**.
So far I have this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE concatenated AS
SELECT
a.id,
CONCAT_WS(';', COLLECT_LIST(a.message)) as messages
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM original_table
DISTRIBUTE BY
        nro
    SORT BY
        nro,
        message -- I'll like to order alphabetically, when I have the same nro
) a
GROUP BY id;
```

I took the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766764/sorting-within-collect-list-in-hive), but it isn't working! The concatenation doesn't follow a fixed order.

PS: I'm not forced to use `COLLECT_LIST`, I can use any function as long as it works.

Comment: Look at this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028484/hive-group-concat-with-order-by  it proposes: `collect_list(s.c) over (partition by s.id  order by s.v desc  rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) ` i.e. that using the over clause may solve the ordering.

Comment: This is actually working. Thank you very much. I was going crazy.