# Query to merge the different values from one column into one unique row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Suppose that I have a table named `order_detail`:

[image]

As you can see that the data is not duplicate but they might be some error from data source about spacing values in the column `Product`.

My goal is to make the table like this:

[image]

How can I write the query to solve this problem on SQL Server? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat single column fields using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199258/concat-single-column-fields-using-group-by)

Comment: @JonathanLam I'm not sure but I had tried and it gave me an error T___T

Comment: Just see that you're using the SQL server but not hive, then it shouldn't have `concat_ws()` function. You should use this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You can also use STRING_AGG() and a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

try following query you get exact output, i have change field name  'Price Unit' to 'Price_Unit' in my query so please take care of that

```
Select ID ,Name,Surname,
Stuff((SELECT distinct ' ' + Cast(Product as varchar(10))
   FROM order_detail t2
   Where t1.ID = t2.ID
   FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Product,
Price_Unit,Date
From order_detail t1
Group By ID ,Name,Surname,Price_Unit,Date
```